# Carousel testimonial auto scroll with description

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design, carousel

I have carousel testimonial, the carousel is working with click on right left arrow, I want auto slide images and particular testimonial person need to heading in top of image and description in bottom of image, as per image slide, heading and description should shows in middle of testimonial for each testimonial member, I have attached the image for reference, of someone have any testimonial section like this so please share with me, please help really appreciated[

```js
<script>
const galleryContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
const galleryControlsContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-controls');
const galleryControls = ['previous', 'add', 'next'];
const galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item');

class Carousel {
  constructor(container, items, controls) {
    this.carouselContainer = container;
    this.carouselControls = controls;
    this.carouselArray = [...items];
  }

  updateGallery() {
    this.carouselArray.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    });

    this.carouselArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((el, i) => {
      el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
  }

  setCurrentState(direction) {

    if (direction.className == 'gallery-controls-previous') {
      this.carouselArray.unshift(this.carouselArray.pop());
    } else {
      this.carouselArray.push(this.carouselArray.shift());
    }
    
    this.updateGallery();
  }

  setControls() {
    this.carouselControls.forEach(control => {
      galleryControlsContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('button')).className = `gallery-controls-${control}`;

      document.querySelector(`.gallery-controls-${control}`).innerText = control;
    });
  }
 
  useControls() {
    const triggers = [...galleryControlsContainer.childNodes];

    triggers.forEach(control => {
      control.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (control.className == 'gallery-controls-add') {
          const newItem = document.createElement('img');
          const latestItem = this.carouselArray.length;
          const latestIndex = this.carouselArray.findIndex(item => item.getAttribute('data-index') == this.carouselArray.length)+1;

          Object.assign(newItem,{
            className: 'gallery-item',
            src: `#{this.carouselArray.length+1}`
          });
          newItem.setAttribute('data-index', this.carouselArray.length+1);

          this.carouselArray.splice(latestIndex, 0, newItem);
          document.querySelector(`[data-index="${latestItem}"]`).after(newItem);
          this.updateGallery();

        } else {
          this.setCurrentState(control);
        }

      });
    });
  }
}

const exampleCarousel = new Carousel(galleryContainer, galleryItems, galleryControls);

exampleCarousel.setControls();
// exampleCarousel.setNav();
exampleCarousel.useControls();

</script>
```

```css
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-item {
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.gallery-item-1 {
  left: 15%;
  opacity: .4;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.gallery-item-2,
.gallery-item-4 {
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gallery-item-2 {
  left: 30%;
  transform: translateX(-88%);
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.gallery-item-3 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 0 60px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45), 0 0 110px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 0 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  height: 250px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.gallery-item-4 {
  left: 70%;
  transform: translateX(-12%);
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.gallery-item-5 {
  left: 85%;
  opacity: .4;
  transform: translateX(-48%);
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.gallery-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.gallery-controls button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.gallery-controls-next{
    position: absolute!important;
    right: 8%;
    top: 58%;
}
.gallery-controls-previous {
    position: absolute!important;
    left: 8%;
    top: 58%;
}

.gallery-controls button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.gallery-controls-previous {
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-controls-previous::before {
  border: solid #ffc20e;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  left: -10px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg) translateY(-50%);
  transition: left 0.15s ease-in-out;
  width: 15px;
}

.gallery-controls-previous:hover::before {
  left: -18px;
}

.gallery-controls-next {
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-controls-next::before {
  border: solid #ffc20e;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
  transition: right 0.15s ease-in-out;
  width: 15px;
}

.gallery-controls-next:hover::before {
  right: -18px;
}

.gallery-nav {
  bottom: -15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-nav li {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 16px;
  width: 10px;
}

.gallery-nav li.gallery-item-selected {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
             <div class="gallery">
             <div class="testimonial-bg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-container">
      <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-1" src="images/events/guest.jpg" data-index="1">
      <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-2" src="images/events/guest.jpg" data-index="2">
      <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-3" src="images/events/guest.jpg" data-index="3">
      <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-4" src="images/events/guest.jpg" data-index="4">
      <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-5" src="images/events/guest.jpg" data-index="5">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-controls"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

][1](https://jsfiddle.net/Sandy_1611/L32q4nzm/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the below code, I have added auto slide functionality with interval time 5 seconds.

If you want to change the interval, Please update the `setInterval` time in the "constructor" and "setCurrentState" functions.

```js
<script>
const galleryContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
const galleryControlsContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-controls');
const galleryControls = ['previous', 'add', 'next'];
const galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item');

class Carousel {
  constructor(container, items, controls) {
    this.carouselContainer = container;
    this.carouselControls = controls;
    this.carouselArray = [...items];
    this.mySlideInterval = null;
    this.mySlideInterval = setInterval(
        this.autoSlide.bind(this),
        5000
    );
  }
  
  autoSlide() {
    this.carouselArray.push(this.carouselArray.shift());
    this.updateGallery();
  }
  updateGallery() {
    this.carouselArray.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    });

    this.carouselArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((el, i) => {
      el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
  }

  setCurrentState(direction) {

    if (direction.className == 'gallery-controls-previous') {
      this.carouselArray.unshift(this.carouselArray.pop());
    } else {
      this.carouselArray.push(this.carouselArray.shift());
    }
    
    clearInterval(this.mySlideInterval);
    this.updateGallery();
    this.mySlideInterval = setInterval(
        this.autoSlide.bind(this),
        5000
    );
  }

  setControls() {
    this.carouselControls.forEach(control => {
      galleryControlsContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('button')).className = `gallery-controls-${control}`;

      document.querySelector(`.gallery-controls-${control}`).innerText = control;
    });
  }
 
  useControls() {
    const triggers = [...galleryControlsContainer.childNodes];

    triggers.forEach(control => {
      control.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (control.className == 'gallery-controls-add') {
          const newItem = document.createElement('img');
          const latestItem = this.carouselArray.length;
          const latestIndex = this.carouselArray.findIndex(item => item.getAttribute('data-index') == this.carouselArray.length)+1;

          Object.assign(newItem,{
            className: 'gallery-item',
            src: `#{this.carouselArray.length+1}`
          });
          newItem.setAttribute('data-index', this.carouselArray.length+1);

          this.carouselArray.splice(latestIndex, 0, newItem);
          document.querySelector(`[data-index="${latestItem}"]`).after(newItem);
          this.updateGallery();

        } else {
          this.setCurrentState(control);
        }

      });
    });
  }
}

const exampleCarousel = new Carousel(galleryContainer, galleryItems, galleryControls);

exampleCarousel.setControls();
// exampleCarousel.setNav();
exampleCarousel.useControls();

</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).